# Help about automatizing process of account creation/posts on article/web 2.0 sites

Tags: linux, automation, webkit, web-crawler, browser-automation

I need ideas how automatic account creation can be done on article and web 2.0 sites. It can not be done with PHP/Curl, because many of those sites use ajax/javascript, and this is not possible to be done via curl.
So, if anybody have idea how this could be done and with which tools(in linux enviroment), please suggest.
I am thinking if than can be done with some HTML Layout engines(like Webkit or Gecko, or maybe some simpler one). It must be possible to access engine API, so we can simulate clicks, enter url and so on.

So, is this possible(it should as senuke did something similar but based on simple version of IE).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that a website us using AJAX or Javascript does not prevent you from using Curl. You'll just have to see what the Javascript code does, and redo it yourself clientside.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, because in some cases ajax create new element in DOM tree, with some id, that curl is not able to obtain(server can generate this id). Or how to solve problem with delayed captcha, that is generated by ajax code.

Comment: If they are using a captcha, they are probably not OK with you automatizing creating accounts and posts? Contact their serveradmin directly, explaining why your automatic service could be a good thing. If they don't agree, stay off their site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)?

It starts as a simple plugin for firefox where you can record and replay scenario's, but you can use the script in lots of programming languages so you don't even need firefox anymore.